# Query string is missing from return url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorization, form-authentication

So, I have an action which is allowed for authorized users only.

```
[HttpPost]
[Authorize]
public ActionResult DoSomething(string data)
{
    StoreData(data);
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

In the view, I call this action:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DoSomething", "Home"))
{
    @Html.Hidden("data", "12345")
    <input type="submit" value="DoIt" /> 
}
```

If the user is not authorized, he/she will be redirected to the login page, but the ReturnUrl doesn't contain the query string(in this case, the value of the "data")

```
http://localhost:62978/Account/Login?ReturnUrl=%2fHome%2fDoSomething
```

Why is that and could I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

When a HTML forms's method is POST the form data is sent in the HTTP request's body. However when a form's method is GET the form data is sent as a part of the URL in the HTTP request.

`BeginForm` will by default render a form with a `method="Post"`. You either need to explictly set the form's method to `FormMethod.Get`. Example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("DoSomething", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
```

Alternatively, require user authorization prior to displaying the form. That is to say add the Authorize attribute to the action that is rendering the view. Example:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult DoSomething()
{
    View();
}
```